# Int64.Parse error: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: .net, vb.net

I know it's a basic concept but today I just keep getting this problem:

```
Dim d As Int64 = Int64.Parse("﻿100618")
```

> FormateException was unhandled by user code: Input string was not in a correct format.

Also tried Double.Parse, Long.Parse, none has worked.

100618 is not a big value that exceeds max value of the type.
So I'm not sure which part is wrong.
Please advise.

Comment: Remove space from parse function and check

Comment: Check input does it contain empty space or a letter instead of numeral by mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When pasting your value into an editor, you appear to have some kind of special character present within your string as this may simply be a copy-paste error :

[image]

Try typing it out and it should work as expected as [seen in this example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HfgGFm).